# Discuss convergence or divergence of this integral

Tags: integration

It is convergent.

$$\int^{π}_{0} \frac{\cosh x}{\left(\sin x\right)^\frac{1}{3} + x^2}dx$$

the domain is $\left(0, π\right)$

How do i show that?
I tried TAYLOR SERIES EXPANSION & GENERATING FUNCTIONAL, it is not better

I already know to use comparison test.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The part from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\pi$ is nice and safe. So from now on we consider **only** the integral from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Throwing away the $x^2$ makes the function bigger. But what's left is "small enough" for convergence. So throw the $x^2$ away.

Now since $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, we find that if $x\gt 0$ and close enough to $0$, we have $\sin x \gt x/2$.

Then compare with the integral of a suitable power of $x$.